# EntityManager is blocking the database trigger

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

In the scenario I prepared, jpa locks the new record. Therefore, the trigger in the database is not activated. How can I resolve this situation?

When I create customer, the code is assigned to the customer by the trigger. However, since the record created during this process is locked, the trigger is not activated.

```
@Entity
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @Column
    private int id;
    @Column
    private String name;
    @Column
    private String address;
    @Column
    private int personRef;
    @Column
    private int customerCode; //db trigger updated
}

@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    @Column
    private int id;
    @Column
    private String name;
    @Column
    private String surname;

}


public class CustomerDTO {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private int personRef;
    private PersonDTO person;
}


public class PersonDTO {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;

}

@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Integer>{
    
}

@Service
public class CustomerService{
    @Autowired
    private final CustomerRepository customerRepository;
    @Autowired
    private final PersonService personService;
    
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = {Exception.class})
    public int control(CustomerDTO customerDTO){
         Customer customer =  customerRepository.findById(customerDTO.getId());
         if(customer == null){
             ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();
              customer =  mapper.map(customer,Customer.class);
             customerRepository.saveAndFlush(customer);
             Person person = mapper.map (customer.getPerson(),Person.class);
             personService.saveAndFlush(person);
             customer =  customerRepository.findById(customerDTO.getId());
             customer.setPersonRef(person.getId());
             customerRepository.saveAndFlush(customer);
             return customer.getCustomerCode;
             
         }
         return customer.getCustomerCode();
    
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Why do you think there is something locked? SaveAndFlush does not read the record from the database so customerCode is not containing the value you are setting in the trigger

Comment: The record I saved with saveAndFlush is updated with the trigger on the database side. When I try to pull the record I just created with findById for the second time, the column updated by the trigger comes up empty. I think Hibernate is locking the record I created. I couldn't find how to remove this lock.

Comment: No findById returns the entity from the first level cache. You have to call refresh to get the entity newley from the db

Comment: What should I do jpa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the trigger runs in the database and Hibernate doesn't know about that.

So you have to refresh the entity after the trigger runs:

```
@Service
public class CustomerService{
    @Autowired
    private final CustomerRepository customerRepository;
    @Autowired
    private final PersonService personService;
    @Autowired
    private EntityManager em;

    @Transactional(rollbackFor = {Exception.class})
    public int control(CustomerDTO customerDTO){
         Customer customer =  customerRepository.findById(customerDTO.getId());
         if(customer == null){
             ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();
              customer =  mapper.map(customer,Customer.class);
             customerRepository.saveAndFlush(customer);
             Person person = mapper.map (customer.getPerson(),Person.class);
             personService.saveAndFlush(person);
             customer =  customerRepository.findById(customerDTO.getId());
             customer.setPersonRef(person.getId());
             customerRepository.saveAndFlush(customer);

             // Reload the data from the database
             em.refresh(customer);

             return customer.getCustomerCode;
             
         }
         return customer.getCustomerCode();
    
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Is there a general solution or should I follow the same method for similar situations?